# sscanf saving into vector

Tags: c++, vector, scanf

The problematic code is:

```
vector<int> Data(2);    
String="ff34";
sscanf(String.c_str(), "%02x%02 ",&Data[0],&Data[1]);
```

As you can see, I would like to parse String and save the data to my vector Data.
I really don't see why this isn't working.

The values I get are:
Data[0]=255 -> this is OK
Data[1]=0   -> this is what isn't working

I've tried with larger vectors, but I get the same. First place is OK, all other places in the vector are 0.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use `%02x` corresponding to `&Data[1]`, as well?

Comment: I can't believe what a stupid mistake I've made.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

`"%02x%02x"` instead of `"%02x%02 "`

See [here](http://ideone.com/Jkhvvg)

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because the format specifier isn't properly written. `%02` isn't a valid specifier, `%02d` (for a decimal integer) or `%02x` (for an hex integer) are.

Answer (score 0):

The code should be:

```
vector<int> Data(2);
string String="ff34";
sscanf(String.c_str(), "%02x%02d",&Data[0],&Data[1]);
```

if `34` is read as decimal integer. And also the supposed type of `String` is `string`.

Comment: You are correct however I have no idea why you would consider that the "34" portion is intended to be decimal (and anyone who intentionally wants the string "ff34" to represent two numeric values, one in hex and one in decimal, needs to put down the keyboard, back away from the computer, and never return).

Comment: @mah because hex number usually begins with a `0x`

Comment: Except when they don't, and the "ff" is a pretty clear indication that they don't in this case, no?